# Accessing fields in a JSON response

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-ajax

I have a class defined like this:

```
// the Widget class has lots of properties I don't want to display
// so I use the displayWidget class to carry just what I want to display
public class displayWidget
{
    public string WidgetId {get; set;}
    public string Description {get; set;}

    public displayWidget(Widget widget)  
    {
        WidgetId = widget.WidgetId;
        Description = widget.Description;
    }
}
```

I have a ActionResult method that ends with::

```
var widgets = new List<displayWidget>();
foreach (var widget in matchingWidgets)
{
    widgets.Add(new displayWidget(widget));
}
return Json(widgets);
```

My problem is, I don't know how to access the WidgetId and Description properties inside of my ajax .done handler:

```
.done(
    function(response) {
        $('#widgetSection').html('');
        var html = '';
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(response);
        $.each(jsonData, 
            function (index, element) 
            { 
                $('body').append($('<div>', { text: element.WidgetId })); 
                $('body').append($('<div>', { text: element.Description }));
            });
    }
)
```

What should be inside of the .each function to output the WidgetId and Description?

Comment: What element.WidgetId/element.Description returning?

Comment: I have no idea... I know that response contains what I expect it to, but right now JSON.parse(response) returns the error 0x800a03f6 - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid character

Comment: Dont' user JSON.parse. Try $.each(response,function(){});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ActionResult is returning an array, try:

```
element[0].WidgetId
```

This will return the first result, you can easily loop through the list if need be.

**Edit**

As @StephenMuecke mentioned, you don't need to use `JSON.parse` here as you are returning JSON data already so something like this will suffice to loop through the results:

```
.done(
    function(response) {
        $('#widgetSection').html('');
        $.each(response, function (index, element) { 
            $('body').append(
                $('<div></div>').text(element.WidgetId )
            )
        });
    }
)
```

Comment: This is not really necessary. All that's needed is `$.each(response, function (index, element) { $('body').append($('<div></div>').text(element.WidgetId ))});` The response value is already JSON so it should not be parsed

Comment: Agreed but his question was how to access the data and that's what I've explained. I assumed that if he knew it was an array (which is what I've explained) he can then go with it from there. I'll update the answer with this information though for clarity for any other users.